# Load an existing database(Oracle) table in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to load an existing Oracle database table in spring boot(Note: table has many columns and rows in it with all the constraints applied). Also, let me know the best way to achieve this. I tried loading this table through JPA but it isn't working. Let me know if any more information needed. Thank you!!

1.SpringBootApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("RecordDisposal.dao")
public class RecordDisposalApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RecordDisposalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2.MainController.class

```
@RestController
    public class MainController 
    {
        public TSRecord tsrecord;
        @RequestMapping("/test")
        @ResponseBody
        public Iterable<TSRecord> Dashboard() 
        {
            return tsrecord.findAll();
        }
    }
```

3.Repository.class

```
@Repository
public interface TSRecord extends JpaRepository<TSRecord, Long> {

}
```

4.Entity.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TSRECORD")
public class TSRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name ="URI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int URI;

    @Column(name ="RECORDID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String RECORDID;

    @Column(name ="TITLE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(254 CHAR)")
    public String TITLE;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHEDULEURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCSCHEDULEURI;

    @Column(name ="RCRECTYPEURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCRECTYPEURI;

    @Column(name ="RCFILEPLANURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCFILEPLANURI;

    @Column(name ="RCSECLEVEL",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCSECLEVEL;

    @Column(name ="RCNOTES",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNOTES;

    @Column(name ="ACCESSIONNBR",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int ACCESSIONNBR;

    @Column(name ="EXTERNALID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String EXTERNALID;

    @Column(name ="PRIORITY",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(5 CHAR)")
    public String PRIORITY;

    @Column(name ="ISPART",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISPART;

    @Column(name ="ISROOT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISROOT;

    @Column(name ="ISRELATED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISRELATED;

    @Column(name ="ISPARENT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISPARENT;

    @Column(name ="ISATTACHED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISATTACHED;

    @Column(name ="FULLRECORDID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String FULLRECORDID;

    @Column(name ="CONSIGNMENT",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String CONSIGNMENT;

    @Column(name ="CURRDISP",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int CURRDISP;

    @Column(name ="RCCLASS",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCCLASS;

    @Column(name ="RCCONTAINERURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCCONTAINERURI;

    @Column(name ="RCACCESSLOC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCACCESSLOC;

    @Column(name ="RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(512 CHAR)")
    public String RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE;

    @Column(name ="REGDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String REGDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="CREATIONDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String CREATIONDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="CLOSEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String CLOSEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="RCDUEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDUEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="LASTACTIONDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String LASTACTIONDATETIME;


    @Column(name ="INACTIVEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String INACTIVEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="RCFINALIZEDDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCFINALIZEDDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWDATE;

    @Column(name ="HASHOLD",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String HASHOLD;

    @Column(name ="RCDATEPUBLISHED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATEPUBLISHED;

    @Column(name ="RCACCESSISCONT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCACCESSISCONT;

    @Column(name ="RCLINKEDTOCOUNT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCLINKEDTOCOUNT;

    @Column(name ="RCRECTYPESECFILTER",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCRECTYPESECFILTER;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTOPARTURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCAUTOPARTURI;

    @Column(name ="SYSLASTUPDATED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String SYSLASTUPDATED;

    @Column(name ="RCORIGIN",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCORIGIN;

    @Column(name ="RCDATEIMPORTED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATEIMPORTED;

    @Column(name ="RCSPURL",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPURL;

    @Column(name ="RCSPGUID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPGUID;

    @Column(name ="RCSPFARMID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPFARMID;

    @Column(name ="RCSPLISTTYPE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPLISTTYPE;

    @Column(name ="RCSPSITECOLLID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPSITECOLLID;

    @Column(name ="RCMEDIATYPE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCMEDIATYPE;

    @Column(name ="RCFOLDERORIGIN",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCFOLDERORIGIN;

    @Column(name ="RC1CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC1CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC2CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC2CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC3CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC3CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC4CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC4CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC5CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC5CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC6CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC6CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC7CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC7CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC8CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RC8CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="SYSLASTUPDATEDBY",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int SYSLASTUPDATEDBY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHINACTIVECALC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCSCHINACTIVECALC;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHINACTIVE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(8 CHAR)")
    public String RCSCHINACTIVE;

    @Column(name ="RCDISPOSALKEY",columnDefinition ="CHAR(9 CHAR)")
    public String RCDISPOSALKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHDISPOSALKEY",columnDefinition ="CHAR(9 CHAR)")
    public String RCSCHDISPOSALKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHDISPCALC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCSCHDISPCALC;

    @Column(name ="RCHASLONGEVITYFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASLONGEVITYFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCHASREDACTABLEFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASREDACTABLEFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCHASOCRFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASOCRFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCCLIENTRECORD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCCLIENTRECORD;

    @Column(name ="RCMATTERRECORD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCMATTERRECORD;

    @Column(name ="RCCONSIGNMENTURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCCONSIGNMENTURI;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTOCONFIDENCE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCAUTOCONFIDENCE;

    @Column(name ="RCDATESUPERSEDED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATESUPERSEDED;

    @Column(name ="RCDATERECEIVED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATERECEIVED;

    @Column(name ="RCGEOGRAPHY",columnDefinition ="SDO_GEOMETRY")
    public String RCGEOGRAPHY;

    @Column(name ="RCNEEDSREVIEW",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNEEDSREVIEW;

    @Column(name ="RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWSTATE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCREVIEWSTATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWSTATEDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWSTATEDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWDUEDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWDUEDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCACLGROUPKEY",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCACLGROUPKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCACLCONTAINER",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCACLCONTAINER;

    @Column(name ="RCACLEXCLUSION",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public int RCACLEXCLUSION;

    public int getURI() {
        return URI;
    }

    public void setURI(int uRI) {
        URI = uRI;
    }

    public String getRECORDID() {
        return RECORDID;
    }

    public void setRECORDID(String rECORDID) {
        RECORDID = rECORDID;
    }

    public String getTITLE() {
        return TITLE;
    }

    public void setTITLE(String tITLE) {
        TITLE = tITLE;
    }

    public int getRCSCHEDULEURI() {
        return RCSCHEDULEURI;
    }

    public void setRCSCHEDULEURI(int rCSCHEDULEURI) {
        RCSCHEDULEURI = rCSCHEDULEURI;
    }

    public int getRCRECTYPEURI() {
        return RCRECTYPEURI;
    }

    public void setRCRECTYPEURI(int rCRECTYPEURI) {
        RCRECTYPEURI = rCRECTYPEURI;
    }

    public int getRCFILEPLANURI() {
        return RCFILEPLANURI;
    }

    public void setRCFILEPLANURI(int rCFILEPLANURI) {
        RCFILEPLANURI = rCFILEPLANURI;
    }

    public int getRCSECLEVEL() {
        return RCSECLEVEL;
    }

    public void setRCSECLEVEL(int rCSECLEVEL) {
        RCSECLEVEL = rCSECLEVEL;
    }

    public String getRCNOTES() {
        return RCNOTES;
    }

    public void setRCNOTES(String rCNOTES) {
        RCNOTES = rCNOTES;
    }

    public int getACCESSIONNBR() {
        return ACCESSIONNBR;
    }

    public void setACCESSIONNBR(int aCCESSIONNBR) {
        ACCESSIONNBR = aCCESSIONNBR;
    }

    public String getEXTERNALID() {
        return EXTERNALID;
    }

    public void setEXTERNALID(String eXTERNALID) {
        EXTERNALID = eXTERNALID;
    }

    public String getPRIORITY() {
        return PRIORITY;
    }

    public void setPRIORITY(String pRIORITY) {
        PRIORITY = pRIORITY;
    }

    public String getISPART() {
        return ISPART;
    }

    public void setISPART(String iSPART) {
        ISPART = iSPART;
    }

    public String getISROOT() {
        return ISROOT;
    }

    public void setISROOT(String iSROOT) {
        ISROOT = iSROOT;
    }

    public String getISRELATED() {
        return ISRELATED;
    }

    public void setISRELATED(String iSRELATED) {
        ISRELATED = iSRELATED;
    }

    public String getISPARENT() {
        return ISPARENT;
    }

    public void setISPARENT(String iSPARENT) {
        ISPARENT = iSPARENT;
    }

    public String getISATTACHED() {
        return ISATTACHED;
    }

    public void setISATTACHED(String iSATTACHED) {
        ISATTACHED = iSATTACHED;
    }

    public String getFULLRECORDID() {
        return FULLRECORDID;
    }

    public void setFULLRECORDID(String fULLRECORDID) {
        FULLRECORDID = fULLRECORDID;
    }

    public String getCONSIGNMENT() {
        return CONSIGNMENT;
    }

    public void setCONSIGNMENT(String cONSIGNMENT) {
        CONSIGNMENT = cONSIGNMENT;
    }

    public int getCURRDISP() {
        return CURRDISP;
    }

    public void setCURRDISP(int cURRDISP) {
        CURRDISP = cURRDISP;
    }

    public int getRCCLASS() {
        return RCCLASS;
    }

    public void setRCCLASS(int rCCLASS) {
        RCCLASS = rCCLASS;
    }

    public int getRCCONTAINERURI() {
        return RCCONTAINERURI;
    }

    public void setRCCONTAINERURI(int rCCONTAINERURI) {
        RCCONTAINERURI = rCCONTAINERURI;
    }

    public int getRCACCESSLOC() {
        return RCACCESSLOC;
    }

    public void setRCACCESSLOC(int rCACCESSLOC) {
        RCACCESSLOC = rCACCESSLOC;
    }

    public String getRCSTRUCTUREDTITLE() {
        return RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE;
    }

    public void setRCSTRUCTUREDTITLE(String rCSTRUCTUREDTITLE) {
        RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE = rCSTRUCTUREDTITLE;
    }

    public String getREGDATETIME() {
        return REGDATETIME;
    }

    public void setREGDATETIME(String rEGDATETIME) {
        REGDATETIME = rEGDATETIME;
    }

    public String getCREATIONDATETIME() {
        return CREATIONDATETIME;
    }

    public void setCREATIONDATETIME(String cREATIONDATETIME) {
        CREATIONDATETIME = cREATIONDATETIME;
    }

    public String getCLOSEDATETIME() {
        return CLOSEDATETIME;
    }

    public void setCLOSEDATETIME(String cLOSEDATETIME) {
        CLOSEDATETIME = cLOSEDATETIME;
    }

    public String getRCDUEDATETIME() {
        return RCDUEDATETIME;
    }

    public void setRCDUEDATETIME(String rCDUEDATETIME) {
        RCDUEDATETIME = rCDUEDATETIME;
    }

    public String getLASTACTIONDATETIME() {
        return LASTACTIONDATETIME;
    }

    public void setLASTACTIONDATETIME(String lASTACTIONDATETIME) {
        LASTACTIONDATETIME = lASTACTIONDATETIME;
    }

    public String getINACTIVEDATETIME() {
        return INACTIVEDATETIME;
    }

    public void setINACTIVEDATETIME(String iNACTIVEDATETIME) {
        INACTIVEDATETIME = iNACTIVEDATETIME;
    }

    public String getRCFINALIZEDDATE() {
        return RCFINALIZEDDATE;
    }

    public void setRCFINALIZEDDATE(String rCFINALIZEDDATE) {
        RCFINALIZEDDATE = rCFINALIZEDDATE;
    }

    public String getRCREVIEWDATE() {
        return RCREVIEWDATE;
    }

    public void setRCREVIEWDATE(String rCREVIEWDATE) {
        RCREVIEWDATE = rCREVIEWDATE;
    }

    public String getHASHOLD() {
        return HASHOLD;
    }

    public void setHASHOLD(String hASHOLD) {
        HASHOLD = hASHOLD;
    }

    public String getRCDATEPUBLISHED() {
        return RCDATEPUBLISHED;
    }

    public void setRCDATEPUBLISHED(String rCDATEPUBLISHED) {
        RCDATEPUBLISHED = rCDATEPUBLISHED;
    }

    public String getRCACCESSISCONT() {
        return RCACCESSISCONT;
    }

    public void setRCACCESSISCONT(String rCACCESSISCONT) {
        RCACCESSISCONT = rCACCESSISCONT;
    }

    public int getRCLINKEDTOCOUNT() {
        return RCLINKEDTOCOUNT;
    }

    public void setRCLINKEDTOCOUNT(int rCLINKEDTOCOUNT) {
        RCLINKEDTOCOUNT = rCLINKEDTOCOUNT;
    }

    public int getRCRECTYPESECFILTER() {
        return RCRECTYPESECFILTER;
    }

    public void setRCRECTYPESECFILTER(int rCRECTYPESECFILTER) {
        RCRECTYPESECFILTER = rCRECTYPESECFILTER;
    }

    public int getRCAUTOPARTURI() {
        return RCAUTOPARTURI;
    }

    public void setRCAUTOPARTURI(int rCAUTOPARTURI) {
        RCAUTOPARTURI = rCAUTOPARTURI;
    }

    public String getSYSLASTUPDATED() {
        return SYSLASTUPDATED;
    }

    public void setSYSLASTUPDATED(String sYSLASTUPDATED) {
        SYSLASTUPDATED = sYSLASTUPDATED;
    }

    public int getRCORIGIN() {
        return RCORIGIN;
    }

    public void setRCORIGIN(int rCORIGIN) {
        RCORIGIN = rCORIGIN;
    }

    public String getRCDATEIMPORTED() {
        return RCDATEIMPORTED;
    }

    public void setRCDATEIMPORTED(String rCDATEIMPORTED) {
        RCDATEIMPORTED = rCDATEIMPORTED;
    }

    public String getRCSPURL() {
        return RCSPURL;
    }

    public void setRCSPURL(String rCSPURL) {
        RCSPURL = rCSPURL;
    }

    public String getRCSPGUID() {
        return RCSPGUID;
    }

    public void setRCSPGUID(String rCSPGUID) {
        RCSPGUID = rCSPGUID;
    }

    public String getRCSPFARMID() {
        return RCSPFARMID;
    }

    public void setRCSPFARMID(String rCSPFARMID) {
        RCSPFARMID = rCSPFARMID;
    }

    public String getRCSPLISTTYPE() {
        return RCSPLISTTYPE;
    }

    public void setRCSPLISTTYPE(String rCSPLISTTYPE) {
        RCSPLISTTYPE = rCSPLISTTYPE;
    }

    public String getRCSPSITECOLLID() {
        return RCSPSITECOLLID;
    }

    public void setRCSPSITECOLLID(String rCSPSITECOLLID) {
        RCSPSITECOLLID = rCSPSITECOLLID;
    }

    public int getRCMEDIATYPE() {
        return RCMEDIATYPE;
    }

    public void setRCMEDIATYPE(int rCMEDIATYPE) {
        RCMEDIATYPE = rCMEDIATYPE;
    }

    public int getRCFOLDERORIGIN() {
        return RCFOLDERORIGIN;
    }

    public void setRCFOLDERORIGIN(int rCFOLDERORIGIN) {
        RCFOLDERORIGIN = rCFOLDERORIGIN;
    }

    public int getRC1CAVEAT() {
        return RC1CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC1CAVEAT(int rC1CAVEAT) {
        RC1CAVEAT = rC1CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC2CAVEAT() {
        return RC2CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC2CAVEAT(int rC2CAVEAT) {
        RC2CAVEAT = rC2CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC3CAVEAT() {
        return RC3CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC3CAVEAT(int rC3CAVEAT) {
        RC3CAVEAT = rC3CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC4CAVEAT() {
        return RC4CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC4CAVEAT(int rC4CAVEAT) {
        RC4CAVEAT = rC4CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC5CAVEAT() {
        return RC5CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC5CAVEAT(int rC5CAVEAT) {
        RC5CAVEAT = rC5CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC6CAVEAT() {
        return RC6CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC6CAVEAT(int rC6CAVEAT) {
        RC6CAVEAT = rC6CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC7CAVEAT() {
        return RC7CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC7CAVEAT(int rC7CAVEAT) {
        RC7CAVEAT = rC7CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getRC8CAVEAT() {
        return RC8CAVEAT;
    }

    public void setRC8CAVEAT(int rC8CAVEAT) {
        RC8CAVEAT = rC8CAVEAT;
    }

    public int getSYSLASTUPDATEDBY() {
        return SYSLASTUPDATEDBY;
    }

    public void setSYSLASTUPDATEDBY(int sYSLASTUPDATEDBY) {
        SYSLASTUPDATEDBY = sYSLASTUPDATEDBY;
    }

    public int getRCSCHINACTIVECALC() {
        return RCSCHINACTIVECALC;
    }

    public void setRCSCHINACTIVECALC(int rCSCHINACTIVECALC) {
        RCSCHINACTIVECALC = rCSCHINACTIVECALC;
    }

    public String getRCSCHINACTIVE() {
        return RCSCHINACTIVE;
    }

    public void setRCSCHINACTIVE(String rCSCHINACTIVE) {
        RCSCHINACTIVE = rCSCHINACTIVE;
    }

    public String getRCDISPOSALKEY() {
        return RCDISPOSALKEY;
    }

    public void setRCDISPOSALKEY(String rCDISPOSALKEY) {
        RCDISPOSALKEY = rCDISPOSALKEY;
    }

    public String getRCSCHDISPOSALKEY() {
        return RCSCHDISPOSALKEY;
    }

    public void setRCSCHDISPOSALKEY(String rCSCHDISPOSALKEY) {
        RCSCHDISPOSALKEY = rCSCHDISPOSALKEY;
    }

    public int getRCSCHDISPCALC() {
        return RCSCHDISPCALC;
    }

    public void setRCSCHDISPCALC(int rCSCHDISPCALC) {
        RCSCHDISPCALC = rCSCHDISPCALC;
    }

    public String getRCHASLONGEVITYFMT() {
        return RCHASLONGEVITYFMT;
    }

    public void setRCHASLONGEVITYFMT(String rCHASLONGEVITYFMT) {
        RCHASLONGEVITYFMT = rCHASLONGEVITYFMT;
    }

    public String getRCHASREDACTABLEFMT() {
        return RCHASREDACTABLEFMT;
    }

    public void setRCHASREDACTABLEFMT(String rCHASREDACTABLEFMT) {
        RCHASREDACTABLEFMT = rCHASREDACTABLEFMT;
    }

    public String getRCHASOCRFMT() {
        return RCHASOCRFMT;
    }

    public void setRCHASOCRFMT(String rCHASOCRFMT) {
        RCHASOCRFMT = rCHASOCRFMT;
    }

    public int getRCCLIENTRECORD() {
        return RCCLIENTRECORD;
    }

    public void setRCCLIENTRECORD(int rCCLIENTRECORD) {
        RCCLIENTRECORD = rCCLIENTRECORD;
    }

    public int getRCMATTERRECORD() {
        return RCMATTERRECORD;
    }

    public void setRCMATTERRECORD(int rCMATTERRECORD) {
        RCMATTERRECORD = rCMATTERRECORD;
    }

    public int getRCCONSIGNMENTURI() {
        return RCCONSIGNMENTURI;
    }

    public void setRCCONSIGNMENTURI(int rCCONSIGNMENTURI) {
        RCCONSIGNMENTURI = rCCONSIGNMENTURI;
    }

    public int getRCAUTOCONFIDENCE() {
        return RCAUTOCONFIDENCE;
    }

    public void setRCAUTOCONFIDENCE(int rCAUTOCONFIDENCE) {
        RCAUTOCONFIDENCE = rCAUTOCONFIDENCE;
    }

    public String getRCDATESUPERSEDED() {
        return RCDATESUPERSEDED;
    }

    public void setRCDATESUPERSEDED(String rCDATESUPERSEDED) {
        RCDATESUPERSEDED = rCDATESUPERSEDED;
    }

    public String getRCDATERECEIVED() {
        return RCDATERECEIVED;
    }

    public void setRCDATERECEIVED(String rCDATERECEIVED) {
        RCDATERECEIVED = rCDATERECEIVED;
    }

    public String getRCGEOGRAPHY() {
        return RCGEOGRAPHY;
    }

    public void setRCGEOGRAPHY(String rCGEOGRAPHY) {
        RCGEOGRAPHY = rCGEOGRAPHY;
    }

    public String getRCNEEDSREVIEW() {
        return RCNEEDSREVIEW;
    }

    public void setRCNEEDSREVIEW(String rCNEEDSREVIEW) {
        RCNEEDSREVIEW = rCNEEDSREVIEW;
    }

    public String getRCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION() {
        return RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION;
    }

    public void setRCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION(String rCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION) {
        RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION = rCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION;
    }

    public int getRCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD() {
        return RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD;
    }

    public void setRCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD(int rCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD) {
        RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD = rCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD;
    }

    public int getRCREVIEWSTATE() {
        return RCREVIEWSTATE;
    }

    public void setRCREVIEWSTATE(int rCREVIEWSTATE) {
        RCREVIEWSTATE = rCREVIEWSTATE;
    }

    public String getRCREVIEWSTATEDATE() {
        return RCREVIEWSTATEDATE;
    }

    public void setRCREVIEWSTATEDATE(String rCREVIEWSTATEDATE) {
        RCREVIEWSTATEDATE = rCREVIEWSTATEDATE;
    }

    public String getRCREVIEWDUEDATE() {
        return RCREVIEWDUEDATE;
    }

    public void setRCREVIEWDUEDATE(String rCREVIEWDUEDATE) {
        RCREVIEWDUEDATE = rCREVIEWDUEDATE;
    }

    public int getRCACLGROUPKEY() {
        return RCACLGROUPKEY;
    }

    public void setRCACLGROUPKEY(int rCACLGROUPKEY) {
        RCACLGROUPKEY = rCACLGROUPKEY;
    }

    public int getRCACLCONTAINER() {
        return RCACLCONTAINER;
    }

    public void setRCACLCONTAINER(int rCACLCONTAINER) {
        RCACLCONTAINER = rCACLCONTAINER;
    }

    public int getRCACLEXCLUSION() {
        return RCACLEXCLUSION;
    }

    public void setRCACLEXCLUSION(int rCACLEXCLUSION) {
        RCACLEXCLUSION = rCACLEXCLUSION;
    }

}
```

5.pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.RecordDisposal</groupId>
    <artifactId>RecordDisposal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RecordDisposal</name>
    <description>RecordDisposal</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
               <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <systemPath>C:/Users/kqxk171/.m2/repository/ojdbc6/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

6.Application.properties

```
#jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@"connection String of the database"
spring.datasource.username=trim
spring.datasource.password=qwerty123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=7
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
```

7. Error message

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface RecordDisposal.dao.TSRecord

this is the oracle table, i'm trying to load in JPA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUqZL.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you've tried. This helps other readers to provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

TSRecord under com.RecordDisposal.dao isn't an entity.

You could try to adjust your code the following way:
RecordDisposalApplication.java:

```
package com.RecordDisposal;

...

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.RecordDisposal.dao"})
public class RecordDisposalApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RecordDisposalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TSRecordRepository.java

```
package com.RecordDisposal.dao;

...

@Repository
public interface TSRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<TSRecord, Long> {
}
```